# How to overcome "java.sql.SQLException: Too many connections" exception?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a simple web application written in java which has servlets accessing the Mysql Database to generate reports. The report generation happens very frequently.

I am using the apache commons DBCP to get connections to the DB. I also close the connection explicity in the finally block always. But i do not explicitly close the Statements and ResultSets i create.

I'm forced to restart the tomcat instance everytime i get the Exception which says "java.sql.SQLException: Too many connections".

How do i overcome this.... do i need to increase the maxconnections in Mysql ?.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your connection is closed?

Comment: have you tried ConnectionPool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes you should close your `Statement`s / `ResultSet`s - These will typically reference the raw JDBC `Connection` rather than the `PooledConnection` proxy `Connection` returned by the DBCP `PooledDataSource`.
- Consider using C3P0 rather than DBCP.
- Consider using Spring to manage your JDBC operations and you will never have to worry about this kind of thing.

Comment: Yes. I think the real real problem is the Statements/ResultSets, because of the first point. When you close the delegated connection (the one who in fact returns to the pool) it doesn't close it's underlying-actual connection (it wants to keep it). So the RS and ST don't close never and ersources are exhausted.
I don't know if C3P0 has something to automatically overcome this, but if you take care of this it must work very well. With DBCP.

Comment: Sorry - My 2nd point about C3P0 was unrelated; you still need to close the Connection and all Statements / ResultSets correctly.  It just seems to be preferred over DBCP (if you search for DBCP C3P0 you'll see what I mean).

Answer (score 0):

Use connection pooling and always close (return to pool) the connection once work is done.

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/connection_pooling_with_connectorj.html

Comment: The OP is already returning the connection to the pool by calling close() on the Connection.