# java.sql.SQLException: Too many connections (MariaDB)

Tags: java, sql, mariadb

I have a server that sends results to client. But after several connection I get exception "java.sql.SQLException: Too many connections".

First I call GetLEDsSettings and this function calls DBS.GetResult(), then close connection. But the connection is still alive. When I execute "show status where variable_name = 'threads_connected';" in Workbench I can see that "Threads_connected" is still increasing. When I restart program, all connections are gone

I tried something from those solutions: 
[How to overcome "java.sql.SQLException: Too many connections" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193603/how-to-overcome-java-sql-sqlexception-too-many-connections-exception) , 
[MySql too many connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069378/mysql-too-many-connections)

LEDs.java:

```
private static String GetLEDsSettings() {

    ResultSet rs = DBS.GetResult("SELECT * FROM ExtLED01_LED");

    String res = "";

    try {

        while (rs.next()) {

            res += rs.getString("LEDname") + ";";
            res += rs.getString("Active") + ";";
            res += rs.getString("Color") + ";";
            res += rs.getString("LEDon") + ";";
            res += LEDcontroll.GetStatus(rs.getString("LEDname")) + ";";

        }

        rs.close();

        return res;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
```

DBS.java:

public static ResultSet GetResult(String query) {

```
    ResultSet rs;

    try {

        TryConnect();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ShellCommunication.SendCommand("LOG -M 'Chyba databáze: " + e.getMessage() + "'");

        Disconnect();

        return null;
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {

        Disconnect();

    }

     return rs;
}

public static boolean ExecuteNonQuery(String query) {

    try {

        TryConnect();
        stmt.execute(query);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
        ShellCommunication.SendCommand("LOG -M 'Chyba databáze: " + e.getMessage() + "'");

        Disconnect();

        return false;

    }finally {

        Disconnect();
    }

    return true;
}

public static void Disconnect(){

    if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}

}

public static boolean TryConnect() {


    if (JDBC_DRIVER == "" || DB_URL == "" || USER == "" || PASS == "") {

        return false;

    }else {

        try {

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            return true;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO exception
            System.out.println("DEBUG1: " + e);
            ShellCommunication.SendCommand("LOG -M 'Chyba databáze: " + e.getMessage() + "'");
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Another Q&A points out that the latest pooling connector seems to have a "connection leak".

Answer (score 0):

Every time your program queries the database, it opens a new connection.  If it does not also close each one -- and it doesn't, as far as I can tell -- then it is bound to eventually exhaust the number of connections the DB supports, which is exactly what is happening.

But note that you must not close the connection until after reading out the query result from your ResultSet, for closing the connection will close the ResultSet, too.  The usual solution for a simple program is to open just one connection and reuse it for all queries.  There are various ways to make that more robust, but that would be a separate question.

Comment: I would recommend using a `database connection pool` instead. It usually solves a bunch of theses issues and is not that difficult to configure.

Comment: I am following these instruction: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/
Using connection pool? Are you talking about this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/#using-a-pool

Comment: Yes. Check `MariaDbPoolDataSource`, `hikariCP` or other implementations like `c3p0`.